# Adding a row to the end of the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, convolution

I am trying to add a row to the end of the array but there seems to be some dimensions issue. So far I have tried this `np.vstack((image[n,:], np.zeros(shape=(1,200))))` here n is the last row in the array. It is throwing **all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly**.
Basically I'm trying to convolve a image with the kernel, for padding the image i am trying to add a row to the array. Please assist me your answers are highly appreciated thank you

Comment: What is `image.shape`?

Comment: your `image.shape` and `shape=(1,200)` is mis-matching check `image.shape` it should be `(x,200)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy concatenate function](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwip-NO9pNPmAhVLzYUKHcApB2MQFjACegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.concatenate.html&usg=AOvVaw3iSom-D1Z7neLwF9kARQst):

```
X = np.ones((5, 5))
np.concatenate((X, np.zeros((1, 5))), axis=0)
```

**result:**

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If we provide axis parameter in append() call then both the arrays should be of same shape.

```py
newArr = numpy.append(matrixArr1, matrixArr2 , axis=1)
```

> try by using axis value as 1 or 0.

Comment: Don't use `np.append`.  If they can't get shapes right with `vstack`, they won't be right for `append`